# wordpress website header login redirect to wp-login.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Hello im new to wordpress and im not familiar with php.
im using tiger theme on my website i have a login form on the body, when i log in it redirects me to myaccount page but the one in the header when i log in with it redirects me to wp-login.php and asks me to log in again.

this is the header-login.php code :

" method="post">
               ">
              ">
              
              ">

this is the home.php code :

```
  <!-- LOGIN -->
              <div id="log-in"  class="active">
                            <form id="login_form"  action="" method="post">
                                <div class="display-hide" id="error_message">  </div>
                              <input type="text" name="username" id="username"  placeholder="<?php  esc_html_e('User Name','tiger');?>" >
                              <input type="password" placeholder="<?php  esc_html_e('Password','tiger');?>" name="password" id="password">
                              <button type="button" onclick="return chack_login();"><?php  esc_html_e('Login','tiger');?> </button>
                               <?php
                                 if(has_action('oa_social_login')) {
                                 ?>
                              <div class="login-with"><p><?php  esc_html_e('Or login with:','tiger');?> </p> <div class="social-login-plugin"><div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:37px;"><?php echo do_action('oa_social_login'); ?></div></div> </div>
                              <?php
                                }
                             $login_page=get_option('_uou_tigerp_login_page'); 
                              ?>
                              <div class="forget"><?php esc_html_e('Forgot your password?', 'tiger');?>  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $login_page) ; ?>"> <?php esc_html_e('Click Here', 'tiger');?></a></div>
                            </form>
```

And the js function :

```
function  chack_login(){

        var ajaxurl = tiger_data.ajaxurl;
        var loader_image = "<img src='"+tiger_data.loading_image+"'/>";
            jQuery('#error_message').html(loader_image);
            var search_params={
                "action"  :     "uou_tigerp_check_login",   
                "form_data":    jQuery("#login_form").serialize(), 
            };
            var username = jQuery('#username').val();
            var password = jQuery('#password').val();
            if( password!="" && username!=""){
            jQuery.ajax({                   
                url : ajaxurl,                   
                dataType : "json",
                type : "post",
                data : search_params,
                success : function(response){
                    if(response.code=='success'){
                        // redirect                         
                        window.location.href = response.msg;
                    }else{
                        jQuery('#error_message').html('<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable"><a class="panel-close close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a> '+response.msg+'</div>' );
                    }


                }
            });
        }else{

            jQuery('#error_message').html('<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable"><a class="panel-close close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a>Enter Username & Password </div>' );
        }   
}
```